# Find Monthly Average of remaining time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008R2, I have a Table named `Timings` which has Column names `StartTime` and `EndTime`.
What I need is to find the difference between `StartTime` and `EndTime` in time only`(HH:MM)`,not the date, and the result which I get after the difference, I need monthly `Average` of that difference.
My Columns are in `DateTime` datatype which are as follows,

```
---------------------------------------
   STARTTIME               ENDTIME
---------------------------------------
02/08/2016 14:29    02/08/2016 14:30
07/07/2016 15:37    07/07/2016 15:37
07/07/2016 15:38    07/07/2016 15:39
07/07/2016 15:39    07/07/2016 15:39
07/07/2016 15:40    07/07/2016 15:40
07/07/2016 15:44    07/07/2016 15:45
07/07/2016 15:45    07/07/2016 15:45
07/07/2016 15:46    07/07/2016 15:46
07/07/2016 15:46    07/07/2016 15:53
07/07/2016 15:53    07/07/2016 15:54
07/07/2016 15:54    07/07/2016 15:54
02/12/2016 9:28     02/12/2016 9:28
02/12/2016 9:29     02/12/2016 9:29
02/12/2016 9:30     02/12/2016 9:30
02/12/2016 9:33     02/12/2016 9:34
02/12/2016 9:34     02/12/2016 9:35
```

So far I have tried this,

```
;With CTTT
AS (
    Select STARTTIME
          ,ENDTIME
          ,(ENDTIME-STARTTIME) AS R
    From Timings
)
Select AVG(Convert(Varchar(10),R,108))
From CTTT
```

I am getting this Error message,

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Operand data type varchar is invalid for avg operator.

I am not good at SQL,A help would be much appreciable.

Comment: what is the datatype of `STARTTIME,ENDTIME`

Comment: Its `DATETIME` datatype

Comment: I need month wise average of remaining time.

Comment: Startime and endtime are of single day only or it exceeds to next day also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working script that converts average datetime difference to hh:mm format.

```
--DROP TABLE #Test
--DROP TABLE #TestTemp

CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    [START]         DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [END]           DATETIME NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT
    '02/08/2016 14:29', '02/08/2016 14:34'
UNION
SELECT
    '02/08/2016 14:39', '02/08/2016 14:47'

SELECT * FROM #Test

SELECT 
MONTH([START]) AS 'MONTH', 
YEAR([START]) AS 'YEAR', 
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(AVG(CONVERT(FLOAT, [END] - [START])) AS DATETIME),108),1,5) AS 'DIFFERENCE' 
FROM #Test
GROUP BY 
MONTH([START]),
YEAR([START])
```

OUTPUT:

```
START   END
2016-02-08 14:29:00.000 2016-02-08 14:34:00.000
2016-02-08 14:39:00.000 2016-02-08 14:47:00.000

MONTH   YEAR    DIFFERENCE
2       2016    00:06
```

For your convenience:

```
SELECT 
MONTH(STARTTIME) AS 'MONTH', 
YEAR(STARTTIME) AS 'YEAR', 
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(AVG(CONVERT(FLOAT, ENDTIME-STARTTIME)) AS DATETIME),108),1,5) AS 'DIFFERENCE' 
FROM 
Timings
GROUP BY 
MONTH(STARTTIME),
YEAR(STARTTIME)
```

Answer (score 1):

You shuold try this. This will resolve you error.

Select Convert(Varchar(10),AVG(R),108)
From CTTT

Comment: Its giving me error,Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Operand data type datetime is invalid for avg operator.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
select DATEPART(month,starttime) as Mon,
DATEPART(YEAR,starttime) as Years ,
avg(Convert(int,Hours)) as Hours,
AVG(Convert(int,minute)) as minutes from (select starttime,endtime,
convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, starttime, endtime)/3600) as Hours,convert(varchar(5),
DateDiff(s, starttime, endtime)%3600/60) as minute 
from timings) as tbl
group by DATEPART(month,starttime),DATEPART(YEAR,starttime)
```